# The current directory is invalid on Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8

I've been trying to run the following command through command prompt as administrator

```
netstat -a -b
```

However I get the following error

```
The current directory is invalid.
```

I tried to follow http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257996 but I don't think mine has anything to do with Logon Scripts

**UPDATE**

Running `netstat -a` as normal user through command prompt works fine. However I need to know which process ID using `-b` option which requires elevation.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same command **"netstat -a -b"** WITH ADMINISTRATIVE PRIVILEGES

There isnt any issue at all.

Here is your Problem:

Like any other program netstat.exe is also a program which is located on the windows directory

Browse to **C:\Windows\system32>** and then type so you should face the program locational issue.

If you are unsure whether c: or d: is the windows root directory.

1.Open the cmd file with Admin Previleges

2.type "cd %windir%\system32"

3.The above step should automatically switch to your root win folder

Comment: I followed exactly as you suggested but I still getting the same error.  The funny thing is the file is written in capital letters `NETSTAT.EXE`. Is this even normal ?

Comment: In windows , NETSTAT.EXE or netstat.exe both are same , windows platform isnt case sensitive, to check further in your issue , plz post a screenshot

Comment: what shall the screenshot contain bro ?

Comment: all the screen to see whats wrong , press printscreen button . paste in mspaint , upload to imageshack.com website and post the link here